# Can I create dockerfile with python windows image with windows 7?

Tags: python, windows, docker, dockerfile

my host OS is windows 7 professional, I was wondering if there I can create a dockerfile which installs python 3 (windows version)?

I tried this but it doesn't work. Is it even possible to create a windows python image using windows 7 as the host OS? Thanks.

```
FROM python:3-windowsservercore
ADD /wheel /wheel
# run pip install /wheel/*.whl
# cmd ["python"]
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm is your docker configured to run windows containers instead of linux containers? The latter is the default upon installing docker. You can switch to windows containers by right clicking the docker tray icon and then select the option "Switch to windows containers"

Comment: Hi, I am trying to create a base python image which will run a windows container. However, as far as I know, the current official image only supports win 10 or win server 2016 but I am using window 7 professional. Do you think if someone else create the image using win 10 and I can still run the image as a container on win 7?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility First sentence says it's not going to work since Windows 10 is the first non server windows which can run windows containers...